# Take a image of a tube that alway spin around in openCV C++

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

First of all, sorry for my bad English,
I have  an object like following picture, the object always spin around a horizontal axis. Anybody can recommend me how to I can take a photo that's full label of tube when the tube is spinning ? I can take a image from my camera via OpenCV C++, but when I'm trying to spin the tube around, I can't take a perfect photo (my image is blurry, not clearly).
My tube is perfectly facing toward camera. Its rotating speed is about 500 RPM.
 Hope to get your help soon,
Thank you very much!
this is my object: [image: img]

Some sample images:

[image: img]
[image: img]
[image: img]

Here my image when I use camera of Ip5 with flash:

[image: img]

Comment: As far as i understand you are trying to get perfect snap of image when its perfectly facing towards camera.
Few parameters that you have to take into account.

 - What is the RPM of your rotating object?
 - What is the quality of image you are looking for?
 - What are the resources available at your disposal, or should i say what all have you tried?

Please share these details so that any person can answer it better.

A simple solution would be having a camera with much higher frame rate, but then your program might never will be able to process it on time.

Comment: Thank you very much #Mayank, my tube is perfectly facing towards camera. Its rotating is 100-500 RPM ( I can change my speed via servo motor's frequency). I have a print mark sensor to detect a signal on the tube and a Encoder to read speed of motor, camera will capture a picture when sensor detected. I have a camera with high frame rate here. Can you recommend me how can I take a picture with this condition, thanks a lot.

Comment: Hi Mayank, "what is the quality of image you are looking for?" - I want to compare the current image and master image if current image have a dirty or fault-spelling, my PC will output to kick it. My project is "Product defect Detection" , thank you very much.

Comment: It the blur due to the motion or to insufficient depth of focus ?

Comment: Hi Yves Daoust, it is blur due to motion, I'd like to a perfectly image of label when the tube spin continuous

Comment: The traditional trick is to take the picture through a mirror, using a set of flat mirrors mounted around a parallel axis and rotating at the same speed in the opposite direction. This is far easier than moving your camera. So in this case it's 500 RPM, which at 25 fps means that in 1 minute you've taken 1500 pictures and need 3 mirrors arranged in a triangle.

Comment: Hi @MSalters can you show more detailed info with your solution plz?

Comment: @ThaoĐặng: If you take a picture of a moving object through a stationary mirror, the picture will be blurred. If you take a picture of a stationary object through a moving mirror, it will also be blurred. The trick is to set up the two movements to cancel each other out. Geometrically it's easiest if the camera distance to the mirror is the same as the distance from the mirror tot the object. From the side, your lightpath would look like this: > . Camera on top facing right, mirror on the right, object directly below the camera.

Answer (score 1):

1. **Motion blur**

   this can be improved by lowering the exposure time but you need to increase light conditions to compensate. Most modern compact cameras can not set the exposure time directly (so the companies can sold the expensive profi cameras) even if it is just few lines of GUI code but if you increase the light the automatic exposure should lower on its own.

   In industry this problem is solved by special **TDI** cameras like

   - [HAMAMATSU TDI Line Scan Cameras](http://www.hamamatsu.com/eu/en/community/xndt/image_devices/tdi_line_scan_cameras.html)

   The **TDI** means **Time delay integration** which means the camera CCD pixels are passing its charge to the next pixel synchronized with the motion. This results in effect like you would move the camera synchronously with your object surface. The blur is still present but much much smaller (only a fraction of real exposure time)

   In computer vision and **DIP** you can **de-blur** the image by **deconvolution** process if you know the movement properties (which you know) It is inversion of gaussian blur filter with use of **FFT** and optimization process to find the inverse filter.
2. **Out of focus blur**

   This is due the fact your surface is curved and camera chip is not. So outer pixels have different distance to chip then the center pixels. Without special optics you can handle this by Line cameras. Of coarse I do not expect you got one so you can use your camera for this too.

   Just mount your camera so one of the camera axis is parallel to you object rotation axis (surface) for example `x` axis. Then sample more images with constant time step and use only the center line/slice of the image (height of the line/slice depends on your exposure time and the object speed, they should overlap a bit). then just combine these lines/slices from all the sampled images to form the focused image .

**[Edit1] home made TDI setup**

[image: TDI setup]

1. **So mount camera so its view axis is perpendicular to surface.**
2. **Take burst shots or video with constant frame-rate**

   The shorter exposure time (higher frame-rate) the more focused whole image will be (due to optical blur) and the bigger area `dy` from motion blur. And the higher the rotation **RPM** the smaller the `dy` will be. So find the best option for your camera,**RPM** and lighting conditions (usually adding strong light helps if you do not have reflective surfaces on the tube).

   For correct output you need to compromise each parameter so:

   - exposure time is as short as it can
   - focused areas are overlapping between the shots (if not you can sample more rounds similar to old FDD sector reading...)
3. **extract focused part of shots**

   You need just the focused middle part of all shots so empirically take few shots from your setup and choose the `dy` size. Then use that as a constant latter. So extract the middle part (slice) from the shots. In my example image it is the red area.
4. **combine slices**

   You just copy (or average overlapped part) the slices together. They should overlap a bit so you do not have holes in final image. As you can see my final image example has smaller slices then acquired to make that more obvious.

   Your camera image can be off by few pixels due to vibrations so If that is a problem in final image then you can use **SIFT/SURF + RANSAC** for **auto-stitching** for higher precision output.

Comment: Dear Spektre, what you're talking, is exactly what I want, I need somethings like TDI to take a perfectly image of label. however, I have no TDI here, could you please recommend me what should I do with my camera? I can try.

Comment: "Then sample more images with constant time step "- you mean I capture a image one a second (or millisecond) ?

Comment: "use only the center line/slice of the image "- sorry for my bad English, what is center line/slice of the image? please Mr Spektre

Comment: I found the line scan camera technology, I think it's suitable to my project? how about you ?

Comment: @ThaoĐặng added [edit1] with some more detailed info. The time between image captures depends mostly on your **RPM** sometimes is second enough sometimes not. You are limited by the camera API so if you can not sample fast enough use overlapping sectors FDD technique to acquire whole surface in more that one round. PS some compact cameras have Hi-FPS videos (like mine 120 and 240 fps) they are low resolution but the exposure time is ideal for this task. I measure Arrow speeds with it `~130km/h` from `~20m` distance so for close tube should be fine

Comment: @ThaoĐặng btw you should add some sample image(s) from your setup (the blurred one) so we can see what kind of blur is the problem more clearly.

Comment: thank for your very helpful detailed info. just one more question: "the exposure time" mean the time between image capture and the next capture? it's shorter mean the frame is more per second? My friend have a camera like this: http://www.chromasens.de/en/color-line-scan-camera-allpixa I can ask him to borrow few days for test. I'll send you my result soon, thank again @Spektre

Comment: I found this code of Petar Palasek for line scan camera:[link here](http://www.eecs.qmul.ac.uk/~pp305/posts/line-camera/) but it's not run with my machine. My PC is using Visual Studio 2015, windows 10 64 bit.

Comment: @ThaoĐặng exposure time is the time the camera integrates photons in the sensor to acquire pixel intensity. The darker the light conditions the more time camera needs to get image. Time between shots gives you framerate (fps) . The exposure time can not be bigger then the time between shots. To override automatic exposure time settings (most camera API's can not set the exposure times directly except the expensive ones ...) you can 1. boost the light by some strong light source 2. use video or burst images it will limiting the exposure time up to the 1/framerate

Comment: So exposure time is shutter speed, this time is proportional with the amount of light that reaches image sensor? this is why I need 1. boost the light by strong light source, right? How about video and burst image?

Comment: @ThaoĐặng yes, The burst or video sequence allows you to either limit exposure time indirectly and also sample images in constant time step which make the construction of final image much much easier.

Comment: I have  take some shots from my camera, but the image is not clearly, I can not find the non-blurred part of my image @@ here my shots

Comment: Sorry, do you have skype or facebook, email? @Spektre

Comment: I added them to your post... so the exposure time is still too high these are single shot or burst or video? if those does not help add strong light... if even that does not help you can use stroboscopic effect so take shot in dark with just really fast flash of strong light.

Comment: This is my demo system, I'm using a Logitech webcam [Logitech][http://i.stack.imgur.com/Uv2Lf.jpg]

Comment: Also It looks like you got pulsing light source (50 or 60 Hz light bulb or neon tube?)

Comment: those have semi-manual exposure time settings in the dialog somewhere (at least mine does)

Comment: you got 8.33 rounds per second so if I assume radius 35mm then the surface speed is 1832.6mm/s if you want to have detail ~0.25mm then you need to take image inside 0.136ms which is really fast shutter for a mechanical system may be using light switching will be better option.  Of coarse the output image will be dark and noisy but sharp ... Also you can use rotating shutter before strong light source ...

Comment: Here my image when I use camera of Ip5 with flash: http://i.stack.imgur.com/o1jqV.jpg

Comment: there you go ... fast flash is your way ... you can try external flash and your webcam ... they will not be synchronized so you need either to capture video and find the right frame or play with camera setting (ISO)

Comment: Capture video: you mean I will take a frame of video (a frame of video like a shot), then take the focused part of each frame. Play with camera setting: you mean I need a professional camera to do this?

Comment: no I mean you start capturing video ... then use flash as many times as needed to cover whole surface. stop video capture. and then go through the frames of that video and pick the focused ones only (that was taken during flash).

Comment: the blured frames will have smooth edges so they are easily detectable by any edge detector + treshold. Also the index of frame used gives you time the shot was taken so you know which part of surface it belongs to for the combination of the whole surface latter

Comment: Thanks Spektre, how about the non-blurred part of image, how can I take it? for example, if I have 10 image of object, the non-blurred part is same position in each image?

Comment: @ThaoĐặng That depends on kind of blur. For out of focus the more sharp area is near the axis of rotation (if focused there). For motion blur the sharper area is where speed vector projected into the camera chip plane is smallest (the outer edges) but the detail there is smaller as you got bigger area covered by pixels there so often that cancels it out. Do not expect you will find really sharp image it is not possible with your current setup You are just minimizing blur as much as you can.

Comment: @ThaoĐặng To decide which kind of blur you have take a shot with rotation stopped with the same conditions and if blurry it is out of focus blur otherwise motion blur. if just a bit less blurry you got both kinds combined. Also automatic focus has often troubles with shinny objects (reflective or transparent) in that case even combining shots will not help. In that case place some focusing marker somewhere near

Comment: [This is my picture with rotation stopped and rotation spin][http://i.stack.imgur.com/a0Tjp.png]

Comment: @ThaoĐặng looks like you got booth blurs. But the out of focus blur is present on the whole surface so it is most likely wrongly focused camera due to the reflectance of the surface. If you can use manual focus (on a webcam) then this will be eliminated if set properly. Usually you need to screw the lens n front of webcam until the image is clear. Another option is place some marker (dull paper or whatever) somewhere and focus on that (in the right distance) for automatic focus

Comment: yes I think I need a professional camera for this. My friend give me a camera like this: [camera](http://www.chromasens.de/en/color-line-scan-camera-allpixa)

Comment: @ThaoĐặng looks really god for this but just to be sure check what  interface it has? Some of these do not have PC standardized interface and need a special grabbing card which is not cheap. If it has USB you should be fine.